# Can I display GUID in windbg?

Tags: com, guid, windbg

I am trying to debug some COM components and want to track down CLSID and IIDs in calls to CoCreateInstance.

I am not sure how to display GUID in windbg. Any pointers for that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the "display type" command:

```
dt GUID [address-of-guid]
```

For more information see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc266712.aspx).

If it is in a local variable (local to the stack frame you're in), use `dv /V` to dump all local variables.

Comment: Thanks for pointer , but this command need to be tweaked little bit.
Following will work
dt nt!_GUID address-of-guid.

Comment: Yeah, if you don't tell it nt! it will search all loaded modules till it finds it.  And, yeah, I guess GUID turns into _GUID.  Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about COM, but if this is just a normal variable (even if it's a global one), then you can always do:

alt+2 to bring up the watch window and enter the name of the variable there, eg

blahblah.dll!guid

You'll need the symbols for that, possibly need t be in source mode aswell. This is slightly nicer than dv/dt in that you don't have to type it in constantly. You can enter the address as well, I think. Note that if you don't put blahblah! then it can occasionally cause windbg to stall for a few seconds as it searches every module for something called guid.